# How to get HTML content of 404 error page using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python to get HTML data from multiple pages at a URL. I found that urllib throws an exception when a URL does not exist. How do I retrieve the HTML of that custom 404 error page (the page where it says something like "Page is not found.")

Current code:

```
try:
    req = Request(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    client = urlopen(req)

    #downloading html data
    page_html = client.read()

    #closing connection
    client.close()
except:
    print("The following URL was not found. Program terminated.\n" + URL)
    break
```

Comment: See [`HTTPError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError). It has a `.read()` method which returns the response content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library?

Just install the library with pip

```
pip install requests
```

And use it like this

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/nonexistent_path')
print(response.status_code) # 404
print(response.text) # Prints the raw HTML response
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the comment that also answers the question, and also because it's what I was looking for, a way to do this without going outside [urllib](/questions/tagged/urllib):

By t.m.adam at Nov 4, 2018 at 10:07

> See [HTTPError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError). It has a .read() method which returns the response content. –